# How to provide proportional auto layout values which will work for different layouts?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, autolayout

I must be doing something wrong / missing the point.

I'm basically trying to create a smaller version of my layout for iPhone using my existing iPad layout. I hadn't previously used auto layout. I'm providing landscape for iPad and iPhone.

I only want to using my storyboard to achieve this!

How do I set proportional spacing when pinning views to one another?

It's fine on one iPad layout size but too big on iPhone.

I'm using constant values.

Just to be clear, if I were coding this, I would use percentages, specifying points doesn't achieve the same thing. So I might have | 2% - gap | view - 5% | 2% - gap | image - 40 % | 15% - gap | etc....

Do I honestly have to install different constant values for each size?

Comment: Some things are traditionally (with good reason) constant in iOS design, namely, standard margins between views are almost always 8, 16, or 20 points.

Comment: So what I do instead?

Comment: Use constants for margins, and let things fill the space. If you need specific proportions, use the "Equal Widths/Heights" constraint with a multiplier.

Comment: @Linuxios what about creating proportional margins, forgot to check if there was a multiplier on them, hmmm.

Comment: I don't think so, but you could create a margin view (wasteful) with proportional size. Really though, unless you have a very good reason, use constant margins.

Comment: Ah well I guess I can install constraints for different layouts, which is just as much effort as a percentage. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use different size classes for iPad and iPhones.[image]

You can specify different layout for each sizeclass if you wanted to.

Comment: Yes but this doesn't cater for proportional values.

Comment: @Jules  - You can also specify multiplier for your constraints like 1:10. But you can specify for all separate device sizes using size class. So there will not be any need for proportional arrangements based on device size as you can set different size class for all different device sizes.